# OSError in Pillow when calling Image.open()

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

For reference, I am using the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.4 on Windows x64, which includes Pillow automatically. I attempted to import Pillow, and it said that the package wasn't installed. I then used `conda install Pillow` to install Pillow. Now I have a different error.

I'm trying to use Pillow to open an image so that I can import it into a numpy array later. My code, simplified, is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('foo.tif')
imageArray = np.array(image)
```

The error I get in the iPython console is as follows.

```
OSError: cannot identify image file 'foo.tif'
```

I've run `conda list` to see if I ran into the same problem as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874485/pillow-not-loading-image-cannot-identify-image-file). However, I get this snippet in the full list:

```
patsy  0.2.1 np18py34_0
pillow 2.8.1 py34_0
pip    1.5.6 py34_0
```

This means that within my Anaconda 3.4 Python installation, there is no conflict between PIL and Pillow.

How do I best go about getting rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in the file. Check integrity of your file before blaming anything else! Used a test tiff from [here](http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/tests/tiff.html) and it worked fine.